# Increment operator value(java)?

Tags: java, increment, operator-keyword

Why does the following not execute to 5?

```
int i = 5;
System.out.println(i-- + (5 - i--));
```

Output:

```
6
```

Since i-- is decremented after the statement is executed and (5 - i--(which should be 5)) = 0 then shouldn't the value simply equal 5? What concept am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For kicks

```
i--              + (5 - i--)
5 (i value is 4) + (5 - 4 (i value is 3))
5 + 1
```

The result of a `i--` postfix decrement operation is the value of the variable before the `--`. The variable is still decremented after it is evaluated however.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3)

> The result of the postfix decrement expression is not a variable, but
>   a value.

and

> the value 1 is subtracted from the value of the variable and the
>   difference is stored back into the variable.

Comment: My tutorial says: "Post Increment(n++) : First execute the statement then increase the value by one." then it should be same for decrement so then why is i-- 4 right away, and not after the line has been executed?

Comment: @someone By _statement_, it means just the `i--`, not the whole expression.

Comment: `5 (i value is 4) + (5 - 4 (i value is 3))` you say "i value is 3" yet you put 4?

Comment: @someone The resulting value of `i--` at that point is `4`, but the value of `i` is `3`.

Comment: As (5 - i--) is inside parenthesis, why it was not evaluated first, making things like: (4 + (5 - 5))?

Comment: @Meraman [Evaluation is still done from left to right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation of equations is done From **Left to Right**

> when the left most (i-- is encountered because of post decrement the
>   value 5 will be used and then decremented by 1.
>   similarly,
>   when the next i-- is encountered the value was 4..

hence,

> (5+(5-4)=6

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating from left to right, we have:

`a = i--`

`b = 5 - i--`

`c = a + b`

`a` = 5 because -- is postdecrement.
`b` = 5 - 4 (already decremented, after this operation will follow another decrement)

`a` + `b` = 6

Answer (score 0):

i-- operation comes before all the others, [see the order here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

so what happens is i decrement first, each time you get to i--, then all the other stuff is happening as you know it.

If you want to explore it more : look for answers for these:

- i++ + ++i
- --i++
- i-- - (i-- + i--)

It's very interesting!